# Upgrade scipy to the latest version

Tags: software-installation, python3

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I have scipy 0.13.3 and I would like to upgrade it .

I have tried:

```
sudo pip3 install scipy --upgrade
```

but I receive this error:

```
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/scipy/_build_utils

copying scipy/_build_utils/__init__.py ->
build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/scipy/_build_utils

copying scipy/_build_utils/_fortran.py ->
build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/scipy/_build_utils

running build_clib
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib
building 'dfftpack' library
Running from scipy source directory.

"object of type 'type' has no len()" in evaluating 'len(list)'
(available names: [])

"object of type 'type' has no len()" in evaluating 'len(list)'
(available names: [])

"object of type 'type' has no len()" in evaluating 'len(list)'
(available names: [])

"object of type 'type' has no len()" in evaluating 'len(list)'
(available names: [])

"object of type 'type' has no len()" in evaluating 'len(list)'
(available names: [])

"object of type 'type' has no len()" in evaluating 'len(list)'
(available names: [])

error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found

----------------------------------------   
Rolling back uninstall of scipy Cleaning up... 
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file__,
'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-h0l8itnj-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scipy Storing debug log for failure in  /home/donbeo/.pip/pip.log 

donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$
python3
```

How can I solve this?  I am working on an almost fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw from reading your question: how can I update scipy in winpython on windows? on Stack Overflow that you want to update scipy to version 0.14. There is an easier way of upgrading python3-scipy 0.13.3 to python3-scipy 0.14.0  than using pip3.

1. Uninstall python3-scipy.

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove python3-scipy
   ```
2. Download the python3-scipy package for Ubuntu 14.10.
   Visit http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/python3-scipy, select the version of python3-scipy that matches your operating system's architecture, select a mirror, and download the python3-scipy .deb file.
3. Install the python3-scipy package for Ubuntu 14.10.
   Double-click on the python3-scipy .deb file that you downloaded to open it in the Ubuntu Software Center, and install it just like you would install any other package. The python3-scipy .deb file for Ubuntu 14.10 has the same dependency package versions as the python3-scipy package from the Ubuntu Software Center, so it should install in Ubuntu 14.04 without any problems.

In Ubuntu 16.04 it is possible to install python3-scipy 0.16.1 from the default Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: can I install it directly with apt-get? Is there any reason of why I should avoid that?

Comment: From the terminal change directories to the directory that contains the python3-scipy .deb file and use a command of the form: `sudo dpkg -i package-name` to install the .deb file. For `package-name` substitute the name of the .deb file that you downloaded, something that looks like: python3-scipy_0.14.0-1ubuntu1_xxxx.deb where in place of the xxxx would be the architecture.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error on a new 14.04 installation.  I fixed it by making sure all scipy dependencies were installed via:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential libatlas-base-dev gfortran`

I believe it was just `sudo apt-get install gfortran` that was necessary.  If you try that first and let us know how it goes, would be helpful.

This was from this thread: https://www.kaggle.com/c/avazu-ctr-prediction/forums/t/12478/kaggler-python-package-for-kaggler

Comment: For me,  just ```sudo apt-get install gfortran``` was enough